# Connection with GPS not working properly.

Tags: ubuntu, gps, ubuntu-16.04, gpsd

I am trying to work out a connection with a gps, but I have not been able to do so, unfortunately. First of all, I tried to follow a guideline from the producer's website:
http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=en:c1_usb_gps
,but after entering the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd` I got a message saying:

```
Warning: Stopping gpsd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  gpsd.socket
Creating/updating gpsd user account.
```

So I decided to edit the file myself using `sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd`. So now it looks like this:

```
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.

# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="false"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM0"

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS=""

GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

Even though, when I use `gpsmon` I get no data back, as If my gps wasn't even plugged. I have tried to check if it is plugged, but I am not certain whether I did it right.

Thanks a lot for your replies!